# When are these late variables initialized?

Tags: dart

I thought about a very easy way to write a translate engine for my Flutter app like this:

```
class Translations {
    static final Map<String, Map<String, String>> _lang = {
        "en_US": ENGLISH,
        "de_DE": GERMAN
    };

    static String translate(String key) {
         final strings = _lang[Platform.localeName];

         if(strings == null) return key;
         return strings[key] ?? key;
    }
}

late final ENGLISH =  {
    "morning": "Good morning";
}

late final GERMAN =  {
    "morning": "Guten Morgen";
}
```

Because I do not want to load all languages at once into the memory I declared the `Map` as late but does this really work here or is the usage in the `_lang` Map already initializing them? If so is there another way of doing it? Maybe storing a Function in the `_lang` Map which initializes the corresponding translation `Map`?

Comment: The late keyword here is redundant since top level variables and static variables are already evaluated lazily (https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules#unnecessary_late). The `_lang` map is also lazily evaluated due to being static, but both the `ENGLISH` and `GERMAN` maps will be instantiated as soon as you use the `_lang` map.

Comment: @mmcdon20 Thank you for the response! Would something like `"en_US": () {return ENGLISH}` help here to not initialize the `GERMAN` map?

Comment: Yes if `_lang` had functions that returned the maps, it would avoid initializing the maps which you haven't used yet.

Comment: A simple way to test for yourself when the map is initialized is to add a key like `"_init_": () { print('init English'); return ''; }(),` to each map. Since the value is an immediately invoked function, the print statement will happen once the map is initialized.